# java command on DOS

Tags: java, javap

with javap java.lang.Object we are able to see the methods signature under it,
where as with javap javax.servlet.ServletConfig  we are not able to see it.

Could any one please suggest any command for checking the method signatures for 
javax.servlet.ServletConfig

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you specifically want a local tool to find the signature, however the best bet is always to look at the API documentation. A google search of the fully qualified class name leads straight to the [official API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html). This will not only show you the method signatures, but often give you valuable contextual information well beyond an argument name or type.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
java -cp <location-of-servlet-api-jar> javax.servlet.ServletConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to locate your servlet-api.jar file and issue the following command:

javap -classpath  javax.servlet.ServletConfig

substitute  with the path to your servlet-api-.jar

Comment: still not working... I am using javap -classpath C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\common\lib\servlet-api.jar javax.servlet.ServletConfig ... let me know if I am missing something...

Comment: Put quotes around the path to your jar and it should work. javap -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\common\lib\servlet-api.jar" javax.servlet.ServletConfig